# i18next + React typescript Custom backend option

Tags: react-typescript, i18next

Hi I am loading the translations from an api. but we have 2 endpoints, first is for guest and other is for authenticated user. for the authenticated one, I need to pass bearer token in the request.  But I am not sure how to do that. I tried adding custom backend but I am getting following error 'Uncaught runtime errors:×ERRORFunction not implemented.'

it expects 'init' in custom backend to be implemented.

Please help.
i18n.tsx

```js
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import i18n, { BackendModule } from 'i18next';
import CustomBackend from './CustomBackend';

const customBackend: BackendModule<object> = CustomBackend as BackendModule<object>;

i18n
  .use(HttpApi)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(customBackend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    supportedLngs: ['en', 'es', 'pt', 'fr', 'gr', 'pl'],
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    lng: 'en',
    detection: {
      order: ['htmlTag', 'querystring', 'path', 'cookie', 'localStorage', 'sessionStorage', 'subdomain'],
      caches: ['cookie', 'localStorage'],
      lookupQuerystring: 'lng',
      lookupCookie: 'i18next',
      lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng',
      lookupSessionStorage: 'i18nextLng',
    },
    backend: {
      loadPath: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE + 'locale/{{ns}}/{{lng}}'}`,
      addPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json',
      parse: function (res: any) {
        return JSON.parse(res).data.content.authentication;
      },
    },
    defaultNS: 'guest',
    interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
    debug: true,
    react: { useSuspense: false },
  });

export default i18n;
```

CustomBackend.tsx

```js
import { BackendModule, InitOptions, Services } from "i18next";

const CustomBackend: BackendModule = {
    type: 'backend',
    read: async (language, namespace, callback) => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('user');

        if (token) {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(
                    `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE + 'locale/{{ns}}/{{lng}}'}`,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                        },
                    }
                );
                const data = await response.json();
                callback(null, data);
            } catch (error: any) {
                callback(error, null);
            }
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Token not found'), null);
        }
    },
    init: function (services: Services, backendOptions: object, i18nextOptions: InitOptions<object>): void {
        throw new Error("Function not implemented.");
    }
};

export default CustomBackend;
```